# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Archivos\

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un proyecto educativo el cual tiene con fin poder ingresar,eliminar,mostrar informacion de personas, pero me sale este error

> ""Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Archivos\index.php:45 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Archivos\index.php(45): mysqli_fetch_array(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Archivos\index.php on line 45""

este es codigo:

```
<?php
$cnx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","clinica_anfr");
$sql = "SELECT id_cedulas,administradores_doctores,id_cedulas,nombres,apellidos,direccion,seguridad_social,citas_horarios,Asistio,no_asistio,doctor_atiende,novedades, as p
          SELECT * FROM `agenda` WHERE 1
            order by p desc";
    $rta = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);
    $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($rta);
```

Comment: Creo que tu consulta fallo amigo, has un `print_r($rta);` para verlo

Comment: Con `mysqli_query`  no puedes ejecutar dos consultas en una, necesitas [multi_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) para ello, por tanto tu consulta está fallando y `$rta` es un booleano con valor `false` que es lo que ocurre cuando query falla.

Comment: la consulta está devolviendo false y `mysqli_query()` retorna false en caso de error, así que hay que revisar tu consulta, que a simple vista se ve incompleta. Para obtener detalles del error puedes poner un `echo mysqli_error($cnx);` e investigar más. O prueba directamente tu consulta en la BD para que veas el error.

Answer (score 0):

la consulta esta mal. intenta asi.

```
"SELECT id_cedulas,administradores_doctores,id_cedulas,nombres,apellidos,direccion,seguridad_social,citas_horarios,Asistio,no_asistio,doctor_atiende,novedades as p
           FROM `agenda` WHERE 1 =1    order by novedades  desc"
```

Comment: Igual si le explicas que tenía mal la query y como la corregiste le sería mas fácil al autor de la pregunta entender donde se equivoco